# osx 10.10.5 Python 2.7 "Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread Abort trap: 6" error

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, boost-python, nupic

I am using homebrew python 2.7 and I installed nupic

```
$ pip install nupic
```

Then I get error when i try to import nupic

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:28:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nupic.bindings.algorithms import SpatialPooler as SP
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
$
```

After I get the error:

> Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
>
> Abort trap: 6

Python exits and it asks if i want to report it to apple.
Here is the report.

```
Process:               Python [72449]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.11 (2.7.11)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [93469]
Responsible:           Terminal [93466]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-02-06 17:30:50.442 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1021)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        855D5299-1DD9-879D-F358-9483D5CA0033

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A2948A3A-B3AB-4F3C-8214-250AAC8AB13F

Time Awake Since Boot: 75000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7800 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85532286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff932e79b3 abort + 129
2   org.python.python               0x000000010a8fa2a3 Py_FatalError + 49
3   org.python.python               0x000000010a8f9785 PyThreadState_Get + 28
4   org.python.python               0x000000010a8f6522 Py_InitModule4_64 + 62
5   _algorithms.so                  0x000000010a0d7c7c init_algorithms + 796
6   org.python.python               0x0000000108fdb98b _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 140
7   org.python.python               0x0000000108fdb422 imp_load_module + 243
8   org.python.python               0x0000000108fc5be5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26858
9   org.python.python               0x0000000108fc9745 fast_function + 264
10  org.python.python               0x0000000108fc5b0b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26640
11  org.python.python               0x0000000108fbf109 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
12  org.python.python               0x0000000108fbead4 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
13  org.python.python               0x0000000108fd7f0f PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 241
14  org.python.python               0x0000000108fdac27 load_source_module + 1089
15  org.python.python               0x0000000108fda689 import_submodule + 267
16  org.python.python               0x0000000108fda24f load_next + 284
17  org.python.python               0x0000000108fd946b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 1195
18  org.python.python               0x0000000108fba70a builtin___import__ + 135
19  org.python.python               0x0000000108f45ef0 PyObject_Call + 99
20  org.python.python               0x0000000108fc9087 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
21  org.python.python               0x0000000108fc438a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20623
22  org.python.python               0x0000000108fbf109 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
23  org.python.python               0x0000000108fbead4 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
24  org.python.python               0x0000000108fe2eb9 run_mod + 53
25  org.python.python               0x0000000108fe2f5c PyRun_FileExFlags + 133
26  org.python.python               0x0000000108fe2aab PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 698
27  org.python.python               0x0000000108ff445d Py_Main + 3137
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9331a5c9 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff56ccd9f8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000713  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff56ccda20  rsp: 0x00007fff56ccd9f8
   r8: 0x00007fff56ccda10   r9: 0x00007fff75557300  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000109d92e94  r13: 0x000000010a4a9010  r14: 0x00007fff75557300  r15: 0x000000010906c310
  rip: 0x00007fff85532286  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff75ea9fd8
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x108f31000 -        0x108f32fff +org.python.python (2.7.11 - 2.7.11) <798BC1F6-00F9-31F0-81E0-2B45D55E8D9B> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x108f3b000 -        0x109031ff7 +org.python.python (2.7.11, [c] 2001-2015 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.11) <006A4B30-6420-3484-A665-DA24EC4C7EC0> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x10924f000 -        0x109251fff +_locale.so (0) <20687CD8-F52A-3BAD-88FB-9BE03FEFC81C> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
       0x1092d4000 -        0x1092d7ff7 +math.so (0) <C55F5074-AC08-3B15-B4F8-84DFBD1ADDC0> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x1092dc000 -        0x109433fff +multiarray.so (???) <5B71DE58-9764-3D6B-A574-757C96F5F7F7> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
       0x1094ed000 -        0x1094f6ff7 +datetime.so (0) <C56B55F8-7D34-3234-88BA-AF4C61C763B3> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x1094ff000 -        0x10955eff7 +umath.so (???) <73DFD541-C165-3D3E-BBD1-C90CFB6E3D3D> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.so
       0x1095cb000 -        0x1095cefff +_collections.so (0) <CD07A4D1-4505-353A-8D97-466AF00273AC> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x1095d3000 -        0x1095d6fff +operator.so (0) <7AFEBDE5-555B-326F-B651-76D5E736B62C> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x1095dc000 -        0x1095e1fff +itertools.so (0) <828A4F03-17C4-3640-AE55-740BFC4409CF> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x1095ea000 -        0x1095ebfff +_heapq.so (0) <1AEE9933-BC4F-3E4E-8AB5-4D9BBB76636A> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x1095ef000 -        0x1095fafff +cPickle.so (0) <7085F368-7F9B-311E-AC2B-2ECF506FE4FA> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
       0x109640000 -        0x109641fff +cStringIO.so (0) <106617DC-C0B4-367F-AE02-790002237B0A> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x109646000 -        0x10964bff7 +_dotblas.so (???) <809BDF78-123C-38FC-863D-9D82F05D21A9> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
       0x10964f000 -        0x109650fff +_functools.so (0) <9F51DD89-251B-32CB-B020-FC70B28C090B> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x109653000 -        0x10967aff7 +scalarmath.so (???) <C15C5850-42F0-3586-B8F6-A666A343561F> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/scalarmath.so
       0x1097cc000 -        0x1097ceff7 +time.so (0) <6EC635F4-E9F9-3DF4-8F22-313F7D892629> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x109813000 -        0x109814fff +grp.so (0) <2DF43676-F9A0-3C6A-8EF2-8E19A6416BF8> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x109817000 -        0x109826fff +_io.so (0) <5614CD2E-13DF-30CC-A724-4D7D8E37F9B5> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x109838000 -        0x10983bfff +binascii.so (0) <A61ACC22-2A70-39A5-B30D-0436E6A38AAF> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x10983e000 -        0x109840fff +_hashlib.so (0) <6705DEE4-D957-3140-9FFA-B93C5EFBBBAF> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x109844000 -        0x109882fff +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <733D4350-77AD-3504-ABFC-E1C41261B9D2> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10989e000 -        0x109a0d8df +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <87599B7D-0474-3047-8362-3279DAB41455> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x109a85000 -        0x109a86fff +_random.so (0) <09D7F46C-1C20-34AD-A904-5973542C197A> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x109a89000 -        0x109a8afff +fcntl.so (0) <0B4E0194-4046-32FB-B2E9-726CBE47D07E> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x109acd000 -        0x109ad1ff7 +_compiled_base.so (???) <5D442C0C-6B62-3A70-968E-2670052500AB> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/_compiled_base.so
       0x109b15000 -        0x109b17fff +lapack_lite.so (???) <6C3A7FF9-1A79-3146-B70C-E69A67999400> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
       0x109b1b000 -        0x109b30fff +_umath_linalg.so (???) <E242EBAE-3418-38E6-896F-CCD1C52F22BF> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.so
       0x109b3c000 -        0x109b3cfff +future_builtins.so (0) <D6C14BF6-23BB-3C57-A53D-5BE766837860> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/future_builtins.so
       0x109b7f000 -        0x109b87fff +fftpack_lite.so (???) <2F049C9E-E682-30A2-B732-FC7A036D13AF> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.so
       0x109bcb000 -        0x109c3bff7 +mtrand.so (???) <DE2327A6-D66E-3B85-A7D1-DD5F868D2ED6> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so
       0x109ccf000 -        0x109cdefff +_ctypes.so (0) <D6A61F6C-676E-3B72-B8DF-8C7B3C094E0C> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
       0x109ce9000 -        0x109cecfff +_struct.so (0) <6AA070ED-02B7-3DE3-9851-0FA49DB24FA9> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x109de8000 -        0x109debff7 +strop.so (0) <E355E7B8-570F-30A6-AE38-ECD08FCE1C8D> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x109def000 -        0x109df2fff +zlib.so (0) <FCB3E46D-4B9C-3A51-8F99-A2720E72AD75> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
       0x109e36000 -        0x109e3efff +_socket.so (0) <1D54A3B9-A146-3B52-A2EC-A531CB2815B1> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x109e48000 -        0x109e52fff +_ssl.so (0) <67DA7263-C866-3DFF-836E-659C527E0494> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x109edc000 -        0x109eddfff +_scproxy.so (0) <3E573FA0-10A0-3614-AD54-07320FFC3452> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
       0x109f60000 -        0x109f68fff +parser.so (0) <1EA858FF-78CC-3A56-B732-E870DF04287E> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/parser.so
       0x109fac000 -        0x109fcafff +pyexpat.so (0) <A2CE4072-E964-3DBD-AB26-E989C7395BA6> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
       0x10a0d5000 -        0x10a51ffff +_algorithms.so (0) <B32F93B6-B3D0-3EEC-A802-D6376794C564> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/_algorithms.so
       0x10a857000 -        0x10a949fff  org.python.python (2.7.10 - 2.7.10) <E4356925-959C-36B1-9991-1D925E7B6C94> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
    0x7fff68d9b000 -     0x7fff68dd1887  dyld (353.2.3) <B1B370A5-479F-3533-8AD7-97B687D4F989> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff83936000 -     0x7fff83947ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff83eab000 -     0x7fff83eabff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.40.1) <4F81CA3A-D2CE-3030-A89D-42F3DAD7BA8F> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff83eac000 -     0x7fff83eb4ffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff84d34000 -     0x7fff84d35ff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <1866C519-C5F3-3D09-8C17-A8F703664521> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff84ec9000 -     0x7fff84f0fff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8551c000 -     0x7fff85539fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.50.1) <1EE815DA-FF1B-3A53-AE9B-C98BD8177A9D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8555f000 -     0x7fff85561fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.40.2) <56F94DCE-DBDE-3615-8F07-DE6270D9F8BE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff85597000 -     0x7fff8559bfff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff856fc000 -     0x7fff856fdff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff85b55000 -     0x7fff85b71ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.30.1) <DDA8928B-CC0D-3255-BD8A-3FEA0982B890> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff85bf7000 -     0x7fff85f12fcf  com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0) <1183FE6A-FDB6-3B3B-928D-50C7909F2308> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff85f2c000 -     0x7fff85f3dff3  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.40.1) <155DA0A9-2046-332E-BFA3-D7974A51F731> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff869cb000 -     0x7fff86b59fff  libBLAS.dylib (1128) <497912C1-A98E-3281-BED7-E9C751552F61> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff86e00000 -     0x7fff86e00ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8798d000 -     0x7fff8799dff7  libbsm.0.dylib (34) <A3A2E56C-2B65-37C7-B43A-A1F926E1A0BB> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff87b8e000 -     0x7fff87bbefff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff87be9000 -     0x7fff87bebff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff87bec000 -     0x7fff87beefff  libquarantine.dylib (76.20.1) <7AF90041-2768-378A-925A-D83161863642> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff88c2f000 -     0x7fff88ca7ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14.4 - 1.14) <3DFFD7F7-BD23-3F4C-A209-C4A0D99F6573> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff899a0000 -     0x7fff899f4fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff89a03000 -     0x7fff89a03ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8a39f000 -     0x7fff8a3a0ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8a3a1000 -     0x7fff8a3b8ff7  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1128) <E78CCBAA-A999-3B65-8EC9-06DB15E67C37> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff8a3b9000 -     0x7fff8a3e1fff  libsystem_info.dylib (459.40.1) <2E16C4B3-A327-3957-9C41-143911979A1E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8a5b8000 -     0x7fff8a5bdfff  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.30.2) <D0E96837-3CF6-323D-B711-6DF6F660E530> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8ad36000 -     0x7fff8ad3efff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8ad93000 -     0x7fff8b1a0ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1128) <F9201AE7-B031-36DB-BCF8-971E994EF7C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8b327000 -     0x7fff8b32eff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8bda2000 -     0x7fff8bdb8ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8bdf2000 -     0x7fff8bdf4fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.20.5) <3F5E973F-C702-31AC-97BC-05F5C195683C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8c836000 -     0x7fff8ca3046f  libobjc.A.dylib (647) <759E155D-BC42-3D4E-869B-6F57D477177C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8cb22000 -     0x7fff8cb5afff  libsystem_network.dylib (412.20.3) <6105C134-6722-3C0A-A4CE-5E1261E2E1CC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8cbcb000 -     0x7fff8cbccfff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff8cbcd000 -     0x7fff8cbd6ff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (133.1.1) <61147800-F320-3DAA-850C-BADF33855F29> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8ccbc000 -     0x7fff8ccbcfff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10) <9D749502-A228-3BF1-B52F-A182DEEB2C4D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8d03e000 -     0x7fff8d044fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.20.1) <840F5301-B55A-3078-90B9-FEFFD6CD741A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff8dd5f000 -     0x7fff8dd65ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.40.3) <BA58B30B-8377-3B0A-8AE3-4F84021D9D4E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff8dd66000 -     0x7fff8dd90ff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.50.1) <A61E703C-784A-3698-B513-75DD12AAD6DC> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e065000 -     0x7fff8e06aff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8ef0d000 -     0x7fff8ef0dfff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.10 - Accelerate 1.10) <2C8AF258-4F11-3BEC-A826-22D7199B3975> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff8ef4c000 -     0x7fff8ef55fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.40.1) <ACE90967-ECD0-3251-AEEB-461E3C6414F7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff8f9c2000 -     0x7fff8f9c3fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff9028b000 -     0x7fff9039dff7  libvDSP.dylib (516) <151B3CCB-77D3-3715-A3D0-7C74CD5C7FFC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff914ff000 -     0x7fff91504ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BE7E51A0-B6EA-3A54-9CCA-9D88F683A6D6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff917f1000 -     0x7fff9186afe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.30.1) <5779FFA0-4D9A-3AD4-B7F2-618227621DC8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff91adc000 -     0x7fff91ae4fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (576.50.2) <9EC5AF92-D0D2-3BDE-92B6-D3730D3865C8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff91eaf000 -     0x7fff91f5efe7  libvMisc.dylib (516) <6739E390-46E7-3BFA-9B69-B278562326E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff91f5f000 -     0x7fff922f7ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff922fc000 -     0x7fff924e1ff7  libicucore.A.dylib (531.50) <CAA7ACE0-4012-3A13-864D-2B56B4B072FD> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff92a54000 -     0x7fff92a7cfff  libxpc.dylib (559.40.1) <5C829202-962E-3744-8B50-00D38CC88E84> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff92acd000 -     0x7fff92af8fff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff92c13000 -     0x7fff92c1efff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061.30.1) <E789748D-F9A7-3CFF-B317-90DF348B1E95> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff9328a000 -     0x7fff93316fe7  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.40.1) <F0635E0F-FE4B-34DB-ACF9-A58C1E9070E9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff93317000 -     0x7fff9331aff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.3) <CFBBE540-D503-3AFC-B5D6-644F1E69949B> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 73166
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=109.5M resident=95.1M(87%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=14.4M(13%)
Writable regions: Total=53.9M written=13.3M(25%) resident=15.8M(29%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=38.1M(71%)
 
REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             44.8M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                          16K
__DATA                             2940K
__LINKEDIT                         75.9M
__TEXT                             33.6M
__UNICODE                           552K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             221.8M

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B14, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

The problem does not happen if I run the native python installed on my mac. The following works just fine.

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nupic.bindings.algorithms import SpatialPooler as SP
>>>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `nupic`, which seems to be a pure python library, probably isn't the culprit here, more likely some incompatible binary module. Try `python -v` to see exactly what module is being imported before the crash.

Comment: Thanks mata, Last few lines are `import encodings.ascii # precompiled from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/ascii.pyc
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/algorithms.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/algorithms.py
import nupic.bindings.algorithms # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/algorithms.pyc
dlopen("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/_algorithms.so", 2);
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread`